# javascript line to be explained

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please tell what mean by the following line of code

```
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
```

what is

```
name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[")
```

the complete function is follows

```
  function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

it's called like this,

```
var getID = getParameterByName('getID');
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? Do you know what `.replace` does? What `/.../` means?

Comment: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" - Really?

Comment: @jantimon I didn't vote either way but the question isn't entirely unreasonable, IMO. OP has identified the exact part of the code he / she is unsure about (which is better than many 'explain dis code' questions), and given that even a programmer that's relatively experienced in other languages may not be able to identify a regex literal in JS, that line of code is a bit cryptic. Still, a look at the [documentation for `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should be enough to point OP in the right direction.

Comment: @Felix Kling  I know what replace does but what does this means : /.../

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just escapes `[` and `]` by turning them into `\[` and `\]`, respectively.

Example:

```
name = 'foo [bar] baz';
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
// name is now 'foo \[bar\] baz'
```

Comment: And there's really no reason for the brackets; `/\[/` works just as well as `/[\[]/`

Comment: Can also simplified to `name.replace(/]|\[/g, "\\$&")`

Comment: @Pointy You are correct. Not sure why the original code includes them. It actually doesn't even require a regex; using quoted values `'['` and `']'` works just as well.

Comment: @p.s.w.g nice improvement!